# Shared Element transition between fragments

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I am attempting to create a shared element transition element similar to that of play music. When you click a card, the album art expands to the ImageView in the new fragment. Then when you click back it animates back down into the card. I have the enter animation running fine, but the problem is the return or exit transition. The app will crash whenever I go back to the previous fragment. Here is the error I get:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getAllowReturnTransitionOverlap()' on
>   a null object reference

Here is how I perform the animation/transition:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                fragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(fragment.getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
                fragment.setReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(fragment.getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode));

                Fragment replaceFragment = new AlbumPageFragment();
                replaceFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(fragment.getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
                replaceFragment.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(fragment.getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode));


                ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.album_card_album_art);


                FragmentTransaction ft = fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, replaceFragment)
                        .addToBackStack("transaction")
                        .addSharedElement(image, "MyTransition");
                ft.commit();
            }
```

change_image_transform.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <changeImageTransform />
</transitionSet>
```

The content_frame is inside the activity's layout view, so both fragments are contained inside it.

My question is: How can I properly use Shared Element Transitions with fragments? Thanks!

Comment: Also you probably want to call `setEnterTransition()`, `setSharedElementEnterTransition()`, etc. in the fragment's `onCreate()` method instead of right before the `FragmentTransaction` is committed. Otherwise if the fragment is ever destroyed (due to an orientation change, for example) these transitions will be forgotten.

Comment: You should be setting the return transitions on the replaceFragment, not the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be something like this

```
        replaceFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
        replaceFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(transition);
```